# VBA Filter and Copy - shorter routine?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to create routine that will sort of shorten the code I have wrote below?
At the moment am replicating the same procedure but for different criteria x number of times.

```
Sub FilterandTrans()
Dim LastRow As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

.Range("N:N").Replace What:="inf", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

LastRow = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Range("$M:$M").AutoFilter
.Range("$M:$M").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Alpha"
.Range("N2:N" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("a2")

'shorten below?

.Range("$M:$M").AutoFilter
.Range("$M:$M").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Beta"
.Range("N2:N" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("b2")

.Range("$M:$M").AutoFilter
.Range("$M:$M").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Delta"
.Range("N2:N" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("c2")

.Range("$M:$M").AutoFilter
.Range("$M:$M").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Gamma"
.Range("N2:N" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("d2")

.Range("$M:$M").AutoFilter
.Range("$M:$M").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Rho"
.Range("N2:N" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("e2")

.AutoFilterMode = False


End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store the criteria and range, and then loop through it. I used late binding, though I would advise using early and adding in the reference.

```
Sub FilterandTrans()
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        .Range("N:N").Replace What:="inf", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        LastRow = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim criteriadict As Object
        Dim key As Variant
        Set criteriadict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'Late bound Microsoft Scripting Runtime is the reference to early bind

        criteriadict.Add "Alpha", "a1"
        criteriadict.Add "Beta", "b1"
        criteriadict.Add "Delta", "c1"
        criteriadict.Add "Gamma", "d1"
        criteriadict.Add "Rho", "e1"


        For Each key In criteriadict
            .Range("$M:$M").AutoFilter
            .Range("$M:$M").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=key 'Alpha, Beta, ...
            .Range("N2:N" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(criteriadict(key)) 'Range Value

        Next key
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Next k <<< invalid control or reference

Comment: whoops should be ```key``` not ```k```.